# vagrant box location on windows 10

Tags: windows, vagrant

I need to change the folder vagrant stores added boxes in

currently it is the default C:\Users\myname.vagrant.d\boxes
I am running windows 10

I have researched this issue and all the answers seam to say I should change my PATH global to add VAGRANT_HOME=my/new/path/goes/here/ however this seams to only apply to Linux
I checked my Windows 10 PATH variables and no reference to vagrant appears there.

Comment: you should create the variable as it will not exist by default - see [here for some windows documentation](https://harvsworld.com/2014/change-vagrant_home-directory-windows/)

Comment: Yup that seams to work - seams the the variable it not set by default